# How to fix an error when working with an array and the find method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question about working with the find method. I have a task - I need to go through the array and find a match with a specific string. But at the same time there is a condition that this string can be inside one of the objects already in its child array. I make an if construct in my function to check this when passing through the array, but it does not work out as I expected. Tell me, please, where I went wrong.

P.S. I write more correctly. If the array object "newList" has "items" , then you need to look for comparison not in the object, but in its "items" array among "role" . If "items" does not exist for the object, then we look for a match in this object among "role"

```
const newList = [
    {
        role: "role111",
        title: "title1",
    },
    {
        role: "role222",
        title: "title2",
    },
    {
        role: "role333",
        title: "title3",
    },
    {
        role: "role444",
        title: "title4",
        items: [{
            role: "role555",
            title: "title5",
        }, {
            role: "role666",
            title: "title6",
        }, {
            role: "role777",
            title: "title7",
        },]
    },
    {
        role: "role888",
        title: "title8",
    },
];

const url = "role7";


export const findAfterRefresh = (list, url) =>
    list.find((item) => {
        if (item.items && item.items?.length > 0) {
            return item.items.find((childrenITem) => childrenITem.role.includes(url));
        }
        return item.role.includes(url);
    });
;


findAfterRefresh(newList, url);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if the object has the items key, then you need to look for a match not in this object, but in the array of items objects

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: If I execute it , it is giving enclosing array for `role7` which seems correct. what you are expecting as a result?

Comment: @User456 get the full value of "role". In reality, "role" is longer than "url" and therefore we check for includes

Comment: @Timofeus91 - Wait, you want `role7` (or `otherstuffrole7`)? Not the item containing it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes. i  need to get the value of the "role" key. Regardless of whether it is in the "newList" array object or in the "items" array inside the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was close, but if you call `find` on `newList`, it can only ever return one of the elements of `newList`, it can't return an element from the `items` array of one of those elements. That plus the fact you want the `role` value, not the element itself, makes the `find` method not a good match for your current data structure (but keep reading; if you really want to use `find`, there's a way).

Instead, a simple loop with recursion does the job:

```
/*export*/ const findAfterRefresh = (list, url) => {
    for (const item of list) {
        if (item.role?.includes(url)) {
            return item.role;
        }
        if (item.items?.length) {
            const childRole = findAfterRefresh(item.items, url);
            if (childRole) {
                return childRole;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here's a version with explanatory comments:

```
/*export*/ const findAfterRefresh = (list, url) => {
    // Loop the given list...
    for (const item of list) {
        // ...check this item's role
        // (Remove   v-- this `?` if `role` will always be there)
        if (item.role?.includes(url)) {
            return item.role;
        }
        // If this item has child items, check them
        if (item.items?.length) {
            // Search child items using recursion
            const childRole = findAfterRefresh(item.items, url);
            if (childRole) {
                // Found it, return it
                return childRole;
            }
            // Didn't find it, keep looping
        }
    }
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const newList = [
    {
        role: "role1",
        title: "title1",
    },
    {
        role: "role2",
        title: "title2",
    },
    {
        role: "role3",
        title: "title3",
    },
    {
        role: "role4",
        title: "title4",
        items: [
            {
                role: "role5",
                title: "title5",
            },
            {
                role: "role6",
                title: "title6",
            },
            {
                role: "role7plusotherstuff",
                title: "title7",
            },
        ],
    },
];

/*export*/ const findAfterRefresh = (list, url) => {
    // Loop the given list...
    for (const item of list) {
        // ...check this item's role
        // (Remove   v-- this `?` if `role` will always be there)
        if (item.role?.includes(url)) {
            return item.role;
        }
        // If this item has child items, check them
        if (item.items?.length) {
            // Search child items using recursion
            const childRole = findAfterRefresh(item.items, url);
            if (childRole) {
                // Found it, return it
                return childRole;
            }
            // Didn't find it, keep looping
        }
    }
};

console.log("Searching for 'role7'");
console.log(findAfterRefresh(newList, "role7"));
console.log("Searching for 'role2'");
console.log(findAfterRefresh(newList, "role2"));
```

Note: I added a bit to the `role` containing `role7` so you could see that the code returns the full `role`, not just the bit in `url`.

---

But if you really want to use `find`, you can do it by first creating a flat array of roles:

```
// Creates a new array of `role` values (the array may also contain
// `undefined`, if the `role` property of any element or child element is
// `undefined`)
const flattenRoles = (list) =>
    (list ?? []).flatMap((item) => [item.role, ...flattenRoles(item.items)]);

/*export*/ const findAfterRefresh = (list, url) => {
    return flattenRoles(list).find((role) => role?.includes(url));
};
```

That code's a big shorter, but note that it creates a number of temporary arrays, and it always works its way through the full `list` **before** looking for roles, whereas the earlier version stops looking as soon as it's found a matching role. That's unlikely to be a problem if `newList` is of a reasonable size, but it's worth keeping in mind. (I'd probably use the earlier version, not this.)

Here's that in action:

```js
const newList = [
    {
        role: "role1",
        title: "title1",
    },
    {
        role: "role2",
        title: "title2",
    },
    {
        role: "role3",
        title: "title3",
    },
    {
        role: "role4",
        title: "title4",
        items: [
            {
                role: "role5",
                title: "title5",
            },
            {
                role: "role6",
                title: "title6",
            },
            {
                role: "role7plusotherstuff",
                title: "title7",
            },
        ],
    },
];

// Creates a new array of `role` values (the array may also contain
// `undefined`, if the `role` property of any element or child element is
// `undefined`)
const flattenRoles = (list) =>
    (list ?? []).flatMap((item) => [item.role, ...flattenRoles(item.items)]);

/*export*/ const findAfterRefresh = (list, url) => {
    return flattenRoles(list).find((role) => role?.includes(url));
};

console.log("Searching for 'role7'");
console.log(findAfterRefresh(newList, "role7"));
console.log("Searching for 'role2'");
console.log(findAfterRefresh(newList, "role2"));
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> ESLint: iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations.(no-restricted-syntax)
>
> ...how much do you think eslnit is right in this case?

That's up to you. If your target environment is ES2015+, there's no need for `regenerator-runtime`. As far as I know, there are no major pre-ES2015+ environments (IE11 is obsolete and discontinued). But if you need to support it and want to avoid `regenerator-runtime`, you can replace the `for-of` loop with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and assigning to a closed-over variable:

```js
const newList = [
    {
        role: "role1",
        title: "title1",
    },
    {
        role: "role2",
        title: "title2",
    },
    {
        role: "role3",
        title: "title3",
    },
    {
        role: "role4",
        title: "title4",
        items: [
            {
                role: "role5",
                title: "title5",
            },
            {
                role: "role6",
                title: "title6",
            },
            {
                role: "role7plusotherstuff",
                title: "title7",
            },
        ],
    },
];

/*export*/ const findAfterRefresh = (list, url) => {
    // Loop the given list...
    let role;
    list.some((item) => {
        // ...check this item's role
        // (Remove   v-- this `?` if `role` will always be there)
        if (item.role?.includes(url)) {
            role = item.role;
            return true;
        }
        // If this item has child items, check them
        if (item.items?.length) {
            // Search child items using recursion
            const childRole = findAfterRefresh(item.items, url);
            if (childRole) {
                // Found it, return it
                role = childRole;
                return true;
            }
            // Didn't find it, keep looping
        }
    });
    return role;
};

console.log("Searching for 'role7'");
console.log(findAfterRefresh(newList, "role7"));
console.log("Searching for 'role2'");
console.log(findAfterRefresh(newList, "role2"));
```

The `return true;` statements tell `some` that you're done, it can stop looping.

> ...and the error on childRole from typescript is TS7022: 'childRole' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

The TypeScript error is just because the code doesn't have type annotations, because it was a JavaScript question, not a TypeScript question. :-) If you add the appropriate type annotations, it'll be fine.

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot. Let me ask you one small question. I am using eslint and typescript in a project and when using this solution i get a warning from eslint - ESLint: iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations.(no-restricted-syntax) .
and the error on childRole from typescript is TS7022: 'childRole' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

Comment: how much do you think eslnit is right in this case?

Comment: @Timofeus91 - I've added to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, You are trying to filtered out the `newList` with all the objects includes `role7` string in `role` property either in main object or in the child array objects. If Yes, You have to use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method instead of [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as it will only returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const newList = [
  {
    role: "role111",
    title: "title1",
  },
  {
    role: "role777",
    title: "title2",
  },
  {
    role: "role333",
    title: "title3",
  },
  {
    role: "role444",
    title: "title4",
    items: [{
      role: "role555",
      title: "title5",
    }, {
      role: "role666",
      title: "title6",
    }, {
      role: "role777",
      title: "title7",
    },]
  },
  {
    role: "role888",
    title: "title8",
  },
];

const url = "role7";

const findAfterRefresh = (list, url) =>
list.filter((item) => {
  return (item.role.includes(url)) ? item :
  item.items = item.items?.filter((childrenITem) => childrenITem.role.includes(url));
});

console.log(findAfterRefresh(newList, url));
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading some of the other solutions I was able to refactor my code down a little bit. I decided to convert the raw array value into a 2d array, each nested array value would hold the role and item values.

I chose to do things this way so that the output of this function can still be used for any purpose regarding the roles and titles of these items. and to create an array which would be easy to iterate through.

```
const url = "role6"; 

const findAfterRefresh = (list) =>{
    let foundData = []
    list.find((item) => {
        foundData.push([item.role, item.title]);
        if (item.items !== undefined) {
            item.items.find((item) => {
                foundData.push([item.role, item.title]);
            })
        }
    });
    return foundData
}

for(let v in findAfterRefresh(newList) ){
    if (findAfterRefresh(newList)[v].includes(url)) {
        console.log(findAfterRefresh(newList)[v].includes(url)); break
    }
}

//output of findAfterRefresh: [[role1,title1],[role2,title2][... etc 
//ouput of the for loop at the bottom: true...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got to it.

Edit: I didn't read the title carefully, the code at the bottom is with for instead of "find" I hope it's not a problem

```
const newList = [
    {
        role: "role1",
        title: "title1",
    },
    {
        role: "role2",
        title: "title2",
    },
    {
        role: "role3",
        title: "title3",
    },
    {
        role: "role4",
        title: "title4",
        items: [{
            role: "role5",
            title: "title5",
        }, {
            role: "role6",
            title: "title6",
        }, {
            role: "role7",
            title: "title7",
        },]
    }
];

const url = "role2";


const findAfterRefresh = (list, url) => {
    for(const singleItem of Object.values(list)) {
        if(singleItem.items && singleItem.items?.length > 0) {
            return singleItem.items.find(child => child.role === url);
        };
        if(!singleItem.role.includes(url)) {
            continue;
        };
        return singleItem;
    }
};


findAfterRefresh(newList, url);
```

Comment: This is a good option, but eslint swears at it and if we have another object after the object with items and we try to find it, then undefined will come. It is link codesandbox with this case https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-firefly-79gzwz?file=/src/index.js